# Character matches neither space nor non-space - whats going on?

Tags: c++, regex, unicode, c++17

It seems that I can match higher order unicode on a char by char basis. But classes/properties does not work well.

I created this sample program (on Windows):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::wregex re(L"\\S+");
  std::wstring c(L"c");
  std::wstring imp_smiley(L"\U0001F608");//gets encoded as UTF16


  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "c: " << std::regex_match(c, re) << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "imp_smiley: " << std::regex_match(imp_smiley, re) << std::endl;
}
```

What is weird is that the 'imp smiley' char matches neither `\S` (non white space) nor `\s` (white space). I would have expected this to be treated as non white-space.

What is going on ?

**Update**

If using `[^\s]+` instead of eg. `\\S+` will actually makes it match. It seems that utf-16 is not being recognized (or *normalized*).

Comment: Are you attempting this on a windows machine by any chance?

Comment: [it's a non-whitespace on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PqZrF6EvzRTemCmS).

Comment: @Frank he explicitly says so in his question...

Comment: @Frank yes, i already wrote that in the question

Comment: @JHBonarius try it with MSVC / on windows

Comment: It is not illogical. ECMAScript 5 standard does not allow matching chars outside of BMP plane. The same issue was present in JS regexp before ES6 was introduced where `/u` modifier appeared that allowed a dot to match any Unicode code point.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why does it match itself then ?

Comment: Match which "itself"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew put the exact char in the regex will match it

Comment: :) Yes, because it is the same sequence of bytes. Nothing wrong here.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole issue: you're using windows.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix ?

Comment: But what is the end goal?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but you just said it weren't allowed to be matched

Comment: You can't match a code point outside of a BMP plane with a character class like `\S` or `[^ ]`. That is what I meant. You used `\S`, you got the comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the end goal is match something like \\S+ while allowing emojis, etc.

Comment: Then use `re(R"((?:[\0-\x08\x0E-\x1F!-\x9F\xA1-\u167F\u1681-\u1FFF\u200B-\u2027\u202A-\u202E\u2030-\u205E\u2060-\u2FFF\u3001-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFEFE\uFF00-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF]))")`. The pattern  is the ES5 equivalent of the `/\S/u` ES6 regex.

Comment: Would it help to switch from ECMAscript to some other format ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type

Comment: try to match to `L".."` and you'll see what's going on... wchar_t != unicode.

Comment: I've found that if i instead do [^\s] instead of \S it matches... anyone know a way to see whats defined in the property class (apart from raw printing)

Comment: @JHBonarius you are correct - just verified

Comment: On Posix (Linux/OS X) machines `wchar_t` is 32 bit. On Windows [as stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=vs-2019) "[...] it represents a 16-bit wide character used to store Unicode encoded as UTF-16LE, the native character type on Windows operating systems."

Comment: That's UTF-16 for you. It is basically broken. Use a third-party library like [boost::regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/regex/doc/icu_strings.html) with ICU support.